# How to draw a square box in the corner of a drawable?

Tags: android, xml

I want to draw a solid box in the corner of my drawable.  I can't use top/bottom/left/right because the drawable can be any size but I want the box to remain the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a RelativeLayout to contain your drawable, and then draw the box using

```
android:alignParent(Top/Bottom)="true"
```

and

```
android:alignParent(Right/Left)="true"
```

to place it in the corner.

Comment: I had originally wanted to do it with a single drawable, but I ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign an id to your RelatioveLayout like, id = relative.
the call it in your code,

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
```

then add an ImageView dynamically.

like

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(size_of_img_on_whom_u_want_to_add*0.2, size_of_img_on_whom_u_want_to_add * 0.2);
```

set params left and top margins as same as the image on which you want to add. the call

```
img.setLayoutParams(param);
relative.addItem(img);
```